# Dell XPS 13 Plus 9320: Ubuntu and touchpad issue

Tags: dell, touchpad, xps

I just bought a new XPS 13 plus 9320. Installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on it. It works well except for one thing. When I plug in the charger, the touchpad becomes laggy with a few milliseconds (very annoying). It's hard to be precise with the touchpad. Also, the cursor jumps randomly sometimes.

If I do not plug in the charger, it works as expected.

I've tested it on Ubuntu 20.04 as well, and there's the same problem there.

I've tried to search around for a fix, but I've not found anything online. Could it be a firmware problem or is it something wrong with the hardware?

The name of the touchpad in xinput is VEN_04F3:00 04F3:31D1 Touchpad

Answer (score 1):

The touchpad issue impacts many Dell XPS laptops, [Dell forum thread here](https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/XPS-15-9510-Touchpad-Intermittent-touchpad-lag/td-p/8012567).
First thing to do is update the [touchpad firmware](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/product-support/product/xps-13-9320-laptop/drivers), the link above is for an UK model update from 30 Sep-2022.
You could boot into Windows to have the laptop updated.